# BPMN Modelling: Parallel Processes, Dependency on Status of an Incomplete Process

Tags: parallel-processing, synchronization, state, modeling, bpmn

I am trying to model a process that splits into 2 parallel threads, where thread 1 progresses independently through milestones, while thread 2 needs to take into consideration its own progress + the status of thread 1 to progress through the milestones. At the end, both thread need to complete. How do I model it? (my best try below)

[image: Mockup]

Answer (score 0):

What you modeled would work. However, you don't need the intermediate events. You can directly connect to the tasks. And you don't need an inclusive gateway. It would work, but a parallel gateway would do the same and be less complicated.

Answer (score 0):

### In short

There is an issue in the way you merge the incoming event with the normal flow on the lower branch.  The symbol used is ambiguous an does not guarantee compliance with the execution semantics.

### More details

The diagram will probably be understood as you expect. But it is not correct from the point of view of the BPMN execution semantics due to a missing synchronisation.

Let's analyse the flow with the concept of token, according to the execution semantics (chapter 13 of the specs):

> A Process is instantiated when one of its Start Events occurs.
>
> Each Start Event that occurs creates a token on its outgoing Sequence Flows
>
> For a Process instance to become completed, all tokens in that instance MUST reach an end node, i.e., a node without outgoing Sequence Flows

So at the start of your process,  a token is created, and it is passed to the first task.  You then have a parallel gateway for a fork:

> The Parallel Gateway consumes exactly one token from each incoming Sequence Flow and produces exactly one token at each outgoing Sequence Flow.

You then have 2 tokens, that will flow to the first upper and the first lower task.  The upper token will continue to the "none" intermediate event. The lower token will reach the entry of a "merge gate".  The question is if we are guaranteed to keep one token on each parallel branch.

The "none" intermediate gate will throw and pass the token down the outgoing flow.  2 tokens are hence generated: one to the next upper task, and one to the "merge gate".

What I called coloquially a "merge gate" is in fact ambiguous in your diagram:

- it cannot be an exclusive gateway, since this would route each incoming token through it. This would mean that in the lower branch we would then end up with two tokens. This would not be legal.
- it could be an inclusive gateway. But the symbol inside should be a simple circle and not a double circle as you have used. The inclusive flow consumes all tokens AVAILABLE on the input, but it requires at least one to get active and does not require any waiting for all tokens to be there.  There is no synchronisation guarantee and you could end up with more than one token on the lower flow if there is the slightest delay in one of the branch.  This is not acceptable.
- Event-based gateways are 2 step gateways. The first is an event with a pentagon inside, and it must have several outgoing flows, each leading to a different kind of event to be received. In this case, it makes no sense, since we do not expect several kind of events.
- According to the book "Real-Life BPMN" written by Freund & Rücker from carmunda, the solution would be to use a complex gateway, i.e. with an large internal '*' symbol and the description of a condition that states that all inputs must be available.  You'd then be guaranteed to have only one outgoing token in the lower flow
- I personally would recommend a parallel join gateway: in fact the two outgoing flows from the intermediate events are uncontrolled flows and are to be understood as implicitly starting a new parallel branch. The join gate would then clearly show the merge of the new implicit branch with the lower branch and clearly document the synchronisation (aka waiting for both token to be available). This seems to be the most appropriate alternative so far.
- An even easier alternative would be to get rid of the lower merge gate, and have two incoming flows for the second lower task. This is then understood as two incoming uncontrolled flows as similar to an implicit join. It's equivalent to the previous solution but with less symbols.

The two last options are the only one which guarantee that there stay one and exactly one token on the upper and the lower branch. The rest of the flow is then trivial until the end.